# Xlib: extension "GLX" missing on display ":0". (Linux Mint 17.2 hipchat)

Tags: xorg, drivers, nvidia

I recently installed nvidia proprietary drivers by:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-current-updates
```

and uninstalled nouveau drivers by

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
```

to solve **standby issues**.

Unfortunately this leads to:

- plasma desktop effects not working (I even manually installed latest plasma)
- **Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".** (*)

(*) For example..

- when running **hipchat** from command line (from desktop launcher It just doesn't work)
- when **running glxinfo | grep -i vendor**

I've found many solutions on SE as well as the Internet but none works (and I'm afraid to mess up further with drivers)

Comment: Did you reboot? Is the nvidia kernel module loaded (check with `lsmod | grep nv`)? What exact model of graphics card do you have?

Comment: @Gilles thank you for your answer. Here is output:
nvidia              11364375  0  ///second line//
drm                   311018  5 i915,drm_kms_helper,nvidia